# Firestore database read count

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my app i use the snapshot listener connected to a collection in the firestore database.

```
private fun getMessages() {
    Firebase.firestore.collection(Constants.MESSAGES)
        .orderBy(Constants.SENT_ON)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            val list = emptyList<Map<String, Any>>().toMutableList()

            if (value != null) {
                for (doc in value) {
                    val data = doc.data

                    list.add(data)
                }

            }

            updateMessages(list)
        }
}
```

In the collection there are 1000 items.
Is my code snippet the most efficient one ? What i want is that a new app user the first time he connects to the database uses 1000 reads. After that due to the snappshot listener only the new documents in the collection.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, and according to Frank's suggestion, I recommend you read the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine at first glance to me.

The only thing I'd do is [add a limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) to the query for what you think is a reasonable maximum that any user may want to see.

What you can consider is [implementing pagination or endless scrolling with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), and only load the even smaller subset that the user can actually see on their device screen.

Comment: ok tx, so if run a query on the firestore database and return the query, firestore will only charge the query reads. In other words the work in the database is not beeining charge, only the returns.